# Passing the method with parameters to the component with avoid unnecessary renders

Tags: reactjs

To avoid rerenders we should pass binded method to example button component without call

eg.

```
<MyButton onClick={this.myOnClick} />
```

I want to create universal component which as next props pass arguments to myOnClick method but i want to be able to pass unknown quantity of elements.

One of the solutions is passing in another props array of args but when i create new array in render method, calls update in MyButton component.

```
<MyButton onClick={this.myOnClick} onClickArgs={[‚first’, {s: ’second’}, ’third']} />
```

Sure, i can create array in constructor but i have renders MyButtons in .map() of data array and i have to pass data from array to args.

> The funniest solution is parse array of args to JSON

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to pass array as property with avoid rerenders or is way to pass method with args to child ?

Comment: Also, if you're worried about an expensive re-render, then you should split your component up into smaller components. Then you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` in the pieces you want to control.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass args in your `onClick` binding:

```
<MyButton onClick={ this.myOnClick.bind(this, 'first', { s: second }, 'third') } />
```

Then in your `myOnClick` function:

```
myOnClick(args) {
    // Do something with args...
}
```

EDIT:

Try using a fat arrow function in the class:

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
  onToggleComplete = () => {
    dispatch( {
      type: 'TODO_TOGGLE_COMPLETE',
      id: this.props.todo.id
    } )
  }
  render() {
    const todo = this.props.todo
    return (
      <li key={todo.id}
          onClick={this.onToggleComplete}>
        {todo.complete ? '✓' : '–'} {todo.text}
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not good solution coz when we bind method on every render MyButton component see diff between current and last binded method, as a result MyButton is updated on every render parent component.